# Convert character to virtual key code

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, keycode

I have a string of values, and I want to simulate key press events in a window for each character.

I plan on sending [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(VS.85).aspx), [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276(VS.85).aspx), and [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646281(VS.85).aspx) events to the window (as that is what seems to happen whan a key is manually pressed).

Those messages require an int be sent in the wParam based on a table of [virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=VS.85).aspx).  I can loop through the string and get each character, but how do I take that character and convert it to a value that corresponds to the virtual key code?  Convert.ToInt32() does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending WM_KEYDOWN/UP is troublesome.  The application itself already translates the WM_KEYDOWN message into WM_CHAR, using the state of the modifier keys (Shift, Alt, Ctrl) and the keyboard layout.  Neither of which you can control, you'll get the wrong character, randomly.

Just send WM_CHAR messages, set the wparam to the character code.  No need to worry about lparam, few apps ever use it.

Comment: It does seem to work, at least with this application.  Thanks.

Comment: True, this answer is probably the best way to go, unless you are trying to __do something else__ with each keydown/keyup, there is no need to send the `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_KEYUP` messages -- nothing magical happens.

Answer (score 12):

[VkKeyScanEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646332%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) anyone? According to MSDN it:

> "Translates a character to the corresponding virtual-key code and shift state."

(You could possibly also use [VkKeyScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646329%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) but beware that it has been superseded by VkKeyScanEx.)

Comment: Also works in C++ ! VkKeyScanEx accepts char and keyboard layout:: Example of english layout `HKL myKL = LoadKeyboardLayout( "00000409", 0x00000001 );` then just `VkKeyScanEx( yourChar, myKL );`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it takes the ASCII character and turns it into hex. For example, 'A' in hex is 41. According to your chart, A is 0x41, which is right (the 0x detonates hex).

Comment: *'the 0x detonates hex'* Ah, the perils of low level code. This zen tidbit does explain a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, instead of sending `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_CHAR` and `WM_KEYUP` messages directly, you should use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) (preferred) or possibly [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28VS.85%29.aspx) (deprecated).

Comment: Can't use SendInput or keybd_event, as it doesn't appear I can specify a window handle. I need to be able to send the message even if the window doesn't have focus

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) library which provides a high level api for simulating key presses and handles all the low level stuff.

Comment: I don't beleive you can specify a window handle with Input Similator.  I want to send messages even if the window doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) is a WinForms class with static methods for simulating keyboard input on the active window.

The catch is that .NET has no way of focusing windows in another application (the [SendKeys docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) talk about how to get around that).

Comment: This is not my preferred method because it requires the target application to be on top. Send char with messages doesn't require the target to be be visible on top.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to use the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) WinAPI function.  [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/94e500c8-6d1b-43bf-9c04-9823597525bf) describes `SendMessage`'s signature and provides a sample import.

Oh and, to map VK codes you should use [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646306(VS.85).aspx) - its best to assume the mapping is arbitrary and not logical.