# c# textBox1.Text converting to KeyCode and send it to a chat program with SendMessage

Tags: c#, string, keycode

I have a Textbox1 and I want send its text to a program that is working by Virtual Keys.

I have these :

```
const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 0x02;
public const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x100;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, stringBulder lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int MapVirtualKey(int uCode, uint uMapType); 

int txL = textBox1.TextLength;
for (int o = 0; o < (txL-0); o++)
{
     int key = MapVirtualKey((int)textBox1.Text[o], MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);
     SendMessage(hwndTarget, WM_SETTEXT, key, new StringBuilder(key.ToString());
}
```

I just want to know if any function exists that can convert any char of TextBox to KeyCode ?
I could write a `switch : case` but this will be too long. (it contain all unicodes languages too :S)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a character to key code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898806/how-to-convert-a-character-to-key-code)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152299/convert-character-to-virtual-key-code

Comment: I saw them but my problem is in textBox1 , it will be fill by my program and i want to convert it to keycodes , btw i want to use sendmessage too.

Comment: `textBox1.Text` is just a string. You're already breaking it into characters. The related questions deal with characters. What's the problem?

Comment: i think ,this function is for VK to char , i want be reverse of it.

Comment: No, it's char to VK. Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2899364/369

Comment: So , can you edit it into my problem ? idk how to use that !

Comment: I'm not going to spoon feed you. If you can't read that question and answer and apply it to your own problem youself, you are going to have a lot of trouble implementing the rest of your program. Did you write the code you posted? Do you understand it? You appear to be acting like a [help vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) to me.

Comment: ok , i tried to use that solving post and it was success for me , but there is a little problem : that function can't retval the "!" and it can't support all unicode characters .

Comment: and this is my problem at there :  `if((modifiers & x) !=0) retval |= Keys.Attn;` what must be "x" ?